# Add an entry to every element in a nested data structure

Tags: clojure

I currently use a data structure like this:

```
(def sample-board 
  [[{:mine true} {:warn 2   } {:warn 1} {          }]
   [{:warn 2   } {:mine true} {:warn 1} {          }]
   [{:warn 1   } {:warn 1   } {:warn 2} {:warn 1   }]
   [{          } {          } {:warn 1} {:mine true}]])
```

Now I want to create a copy of the first structure and each element should be supplemented with :explored true.

My approach so far looks like this:

```
(def sample-board-solved
  (map (partial map 
                (partial conj {:explored true})) 
       sample-board))
```

I don't find the approach very appealing though. I thought about using [for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) instead or maybe [recur](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur) in combination with [update-in](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) but I did not bring it to work yet.

I'd be glad on suggestions how to improve the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could maybe make your solution a bit neater by using a lambda in place of one of your partials.  `assoc` might be a little clearer in purpose than a `conj` as well:

```clj
(def sample-board-solved
  (map (partial map #(assoc % :explored true))
       sample-board))
```

Using map like this will return things in sequences rather than vectors like the input data.  If it's particularly important that you get vectors out you can always use `mapv`

Comment: +1. Also, if this pattern happens a lot, OP could define a 2-depth or "board-cell-level" map: `(defn mapmap [f coll] (map (partial map f) coll))`